# how to run xampp on cd?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, cd

I have a product catalog using apache, php and mysql. I need to put it on a CD, so it can be run from it direclty. What possibilities are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found this links in google :

http://www.pendriveapps.com/xampp-portable-web-server/

or

http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=89461

Put AMPstart.exe in the XAMPP(Lite) folder (with AMPstart.ini or not) and start it.

AMPstart.ini

```
;--- start of ini file ---
[database]
overwrite= ;''=do nothing; 1=overwrite; 0=copy; 
folder=copy\DB\to ;use only when overwrite=0 or 1

[website]
website=test ;htdocs\test
startup= ;index.php as default

[cd]
eject= ;1=eject CD door when shut down
;--- end of ini file ---
```

The relative path in AMPstart.ini comes from the location of AMPstart.ini.

AMPstart starts as an icon in system tray. It finds AMPstart.ini at AMPstart.exe's folder, then root folder of every drive of your system (but network drive). After loading the web server, it locks CD door, starts your home page (see AMPstart.ini).

Double click on AMPstart's icon to shut down the web server and unlock the drive.

Download:
http://download.yousendit.com/66CC92C372536A48

Answer (score 1):

I've also found this one:

http://www.dwebpro.com/

looks good